# python join key and values from a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks similar to this one :

```
mydic = {'key1':['va1','va2'], 'key2':['vb1','vb2']}
```

I would like to print file path out these, e.g.

```
/path/to/dir/key1/dir2/va1
/path/to/dir/key1/dir2/va2
/path/to/dir/key2/dir2/vb1
/path/to/dir/key3/dir2/vb2
```

I have tried,

```
for k, v in mydic.iteritems():
    print "/path/to/dir/k/dir2/v"
```

But this one prints out `v` as a list. How can I achieve the above ? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.path.join()`, like this:

```
import os

mydic = {'key1':['va1','va2'], 'key2':['vb1','vb2']}


BASE_DIR = os.path.join('path', 'to', 'dir')
ADD_DIR = 'dir2'
for k, v in mydic.iteritems():
    for item in v:
        print os.path.join(BASE_DIR, k, ADD_DIR, item)
```

prints:

```
/path/to/dir/key2/dir2/vb1
/path/to/dir/key2/dir2/vb2
/path/to/dir/key1/dir2/va1
/path/to/dir/key1/dir2/va2
```

Comment: This mixes up back and forward slashes in windows. Maybe use `BASE_DIR=os.path.join('path', 'to', 'dir')` instead?